# Haar measure for profinite groups (reference needed)

Tags: profinite-groups

I was wondering if anybody knows a good reference book or exposition for Haar measures over profinite groups (with some concrete examples and computations)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bill Casselman has [a very nice set of notes.](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/Profinite.pdf)